# UILongPressGestureRecognizer recognizes touches outside its view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `subview` of `imageview` with a `PanGestureRecognizer`, and the main view has a `LongPressGestureRecognizer`. I have added the `longpress` only to the view like this:

```
screenRecognize = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(screenTaped:)];
screenRecognize.minimumPressDuration = 0.0;
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self addGestureRecognizer:screenRecognize];
```

And here's the imageview:

```
imageViewPanRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewPulled:)];

imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(310, 50, 10, 40)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:imageViewPanRecognizer];
[self addSubview:imageView];
```

When I touch the `imageView`, the `UILongPressRecognizer` is fired. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is already in your question.  You set

```
screenRecognize.minimumPressDuration = 0.0;
```

that means, UILongPressGestureRecognizer will work as like UITapGestureRecognizer. By the line

```
[self addGestureRecognizer:screenRecognize];
```

you active this gesture on all over the **self**.

Now when you add imageView in the **self**, the imageView will also response to the UILongPressGestureRecognizer as well as UIPanGestureRecognizer which is only active on the imageView. As a result touching on the imageView is firing UILongPressGestureRecognizer.

To solve this problem you can try by increasing the *minimumPressDuration* value.

Answer (score 0):

1) Why you use long gesture with minimumPressDuration=0? Can not properly use pan gesture?

2) If you want that gestures work together, try something like this:

```
longGesture.delegate = self;
...
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

3) If you whan if user pan to UIImageView long gesture disable, try something like this:

```
self.tag = 1;
longGesture.delegate = self;
...
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return touch.view.tag == 1;
}
```